# How to Retrieve Agent id in Anylogic 7.3.1

Tags: anylogic

I am implementing bank office sample of Anylogic 7.3.1 . I have created 20 agents in my source block. I want to assign agent id when any agent enters to the source.
I have write this block of code for this.

```
agent.enteredSystem = time();
if(agent.enteredSystem > 0)
{
if(count <100)
{
String customerId = "CId-";
customerId = customerId + count;
count++;
}   
}
```

there is one customer class where I have declared enteredSystem variable as double. count is static variable declared in graphical editor of main class.

I want to move this customerId  to queue block and then delay but when I am writing it in text file . there is repetition of customerId .
help me. thanks in advance..

Comment: time() will always be larger or equal to zero, not sure why the first if-statement is needed.

Comment: Did you write this code in the "On exit" code box of your Source?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you need to define your customerID variables as part of the Customer class, not embedded in your if-statements.